# LightSwitch VS Deployment Error Message: "Only members on the system admin role or the database owner can set the compatibility level"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment, runtime-error, lightswitch-2012

My team and I are developing a desktop application for an Information Systems course in South Africa. The application is created on the C# LightSwitch Application on Visual Studio 2012.

We tried to do a test deployment of the application, however we get the following error: "Only members on the system admin role or the database owner can set the compatibility level"

We have followed all the instructions according to: **How to: Deploy a Two-tier LightSwitch Application** at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852056.aspx

And still no luck.

Please could someone tell us how to fix this issue?